# MVC WebGrid Custom URL's For Sorting & Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, html-helper, webgrid

I have been trying to fin a way to override the URL generated for sorting & paging. As i need to put a session ID in the URL that it generates. I have tried putting in custom formats. But that didn't work. It there an easier way?

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", rowsPerPage: @Model.Paging.PageSize, defaultSort: "Test");
grid.Bind(Model.TestUnit, rowCount: Model.Paging.TotalRecordCount, autoSortAndPage: false, );
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast, firstText: "First", lastText: "Last");
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("", format: @<img class="thumb" src="#" height="35" width="35" alt="" />),
    grid.Column("Test", header: "Test"),
    grid.Column("Test2", header: "Test2"),
    grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.test}) </text>, canSort: false)
                            ));
}
```

Comment: If you want to make the session ID appear in the URL, I thought there was a simple option to make it cookieless and then any URLs generated will have the session ID in the query string?

Comment: Is it too late to use a better and totally free grid like http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/ ?

Comment: Lets take a step back and ask why you want to put a session id in the URL?

Comment: We arnt allowed to use cookies, so we carry around a session ID in the URL. It works fine everywhere else apart from the grid.